# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled exceptioln on 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com

I am running a VS project and I am running a project on a different machine and I getting these errors when I run.

The processors of the two machines are the same 64 bit and I have my project build property set to x86.

Any ideas what I can try? I tried changing it to any CPU and that did not work.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>     Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {31005F02-3BF5-4F1E-BA5E-5910727C563B} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
>     Source=L
>     ErrorCode=-2147221164

Comment: You mentioned that you have a project on Visual Studio and a 'different machine'. Does it work on the first and does not work on the other? or does it not work on both machines?

Comment: It works on one machine but not the other. I built from Perforce so I have the latest code. What does that error mean?  The CLSID object is not regestered from what I've seen. How can it not be registered? The machines both have same operating system.

Comment: It may be a symptom that the com component you are using is missing other dependencies that you have on your development machine but not on the other one. Try running listdlls on the process that works and see whether these dlls exist on the other machine. This is a sysinternals tool and you can find more details @ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx